# Is it possible to make an HTML datetime-local element produce only valid dates?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I am using an HTML `datetime-local` element to get a datetime from the user. The problem with this input field is that it allows the user to input values that cannot be converted to JavaScript `Date` objects. Some possible inputs are too large, for example the following date is too large:

[image: invalid date]

Here is what happens when I get its value using JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementById("__Date");
var time = input.value; // is "121212-12-12T12:12" right now
var value = new Date(time); // I get an error here - "Invalid Date"
```

Here is the complete element in question. I am using Google Chrome v37 to run this code.

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="input-block-level EditableAttributeValue" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="__Date" max="2015-00-00T00:00:00:00">
```

I need a way to disallow these invalid inputs, preferably without using any JavaScript to listen to changes and validate the input by hand.

Comment: Can't really do it without JavaScript. You're at the mercy of the browser. Go with a JavaScript solution, there's plenty of date/ time format libraries out there, and plenty of date/time pickers.

Comment: The JavaScript code does not match the HTML code (different `id` value). Maku sure you include *real* code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: There is max attribute in the html, why doesn't that fix the issue?

Comment: The `max` attribute just sets a validation criterion. It need not prevent the user from entering a value that violates the criterion; it is meant to let a page detect, in CSS and/or in JavaScript, that some input is not acceptable.'

Comment: The `type=datetime` feature has poor browser support: basically only in WebKit browsers, with many bugs (e.g., `max` attribute appearently not supported). It has therefore been dropped from W3C HTML5 CR. Consider using a different approach, like separate controls for date and time or some library routine.

Comment: The project I'm working on targets Chrome and WebKit specifically, so this works for the time being. If I ever need to port to other browsers, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that although the value of the `datetime-local` cannot be parsed using the `Date()` object, you can get a valid date through the `input.valueAsNumber` property and then converting to a date. This fixes the problem and removes the need for that kind of validation. Use as follows:

```
var input = document.getElementById("__Date");
var dateNumber = input.valueAsNumber; 
var date = new Date(dateNumber); // this is a valid date now - "Tue Dec 11 121212 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
```

Comment: I get `null` when I test this in Chrome 37 (Win 7).

Comment: Try this website: http://javascriptref.com/3ed/ch13/valueasdate.html, inputing any date seems to work.

Comment: On second thought, that shows only `date`, and here I am using a `datetime-local`. I fixed my answer to make it work for `datetime-local` inputs.

Comment: Now it fixes the problem with the `Date()` method, but it does not address the question in the title. The code still accepts times past the `max` value.

Comment: The max attribute was an attempt to prevent dates that are too large to be parsed from being submitted. I don't need any real max-date.